# Issue with MS Graph Onenote get Notebooks API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote

I am using MS graph API to get all notebooks including shared notebooks using: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/notebooks?includesharednotebooks=true`

Sample response I received on API call is as -
[image]

In this notebook with `"displayName": "For pooja"` is created by another user and shared with me.  Notebook with `"displayName": "Pooja_Work_1"` is created by me. In `createdBy` field for the notebook created by me reflects the correct user `id` and `displayName`. Whereas for the notebook shared with me the `createdBy` field user `displayName` has correct value but user `id` has my `id`. Ideally it must be user's `id` who has created this.

Seems like a bug in API.

In order to access the shared notebook how I can get `userId` of user who has shared notebook with me. On `groupId` in case of group shared notebooks.

Both users belong to same organisation.

Comment: I can't think of a way to get it. This is most likely why `includesharednotebooks=true` is not documented.

Comment: In there any way to get id of the user who has shared the notebook with me. I have list of notebooks shared with me.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry Pooja. Currently this is a known limitation in this particular API. We are unable to retrieve the ID of the user who created or modified the shared notebook. Hence, the ID is currently set to the request user

Comment: So is there any way for business account I can retrieve the shared notebook pages and sections. I am badly stuck with this issue. How I can know about the user who has shared notebook with me . There is no way to access pages from shared notebook for business account ?

Comment: Do you see the desired notebooks in the GetRecentNotebooks API response? For reference: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/notebook_getrecentnotebooks

Comment: Yes @Manjusha I am able to access the shared notebooks but somehow I am not able to access the pages and sections for those notebooks.  Is there any way to access the pages and sections of shared notebooks

Comment: Are you able to see those shared notebooks in the "GetRecentNotebooks" API response?

Comment: Yes I am able to see the titles and web URL of those notebook

Comment: So here's what you can do to unblock yourself:1.Copy the siteUrl (url part before the /documents) and use the OneNote FromUrl API to get the sitecollectionId and siteId. FromUrl reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/onenote-get-content => Use the FromUrl method 2.And then use the SharePoint sites route in Microsoft Graph to retrieve the notebook id that you want. See https://dev.office.com/blogs/onenote-api-for-sharepoint-site-hosted-notebooks-in-microsoft-graph-v1. 3.At this point, you can also retrieve the sections and pages of this shared notebook

Comment: The {sitesId} is in the composite comma-separated format like firstsegmentafterhttpsintheurlabove,siteCollectionIdfromtheFromUrl,siteIdfromtheFromUrl

Comment: Thank you this worked for me. Can I get any equivalent implementation using MS Graph API

Comment: I have already implemented few things using MS Graph and don't want to switch to Onenote API . I tried similar thing with MS Graph API but it didn't work. I could not fetch siteURL from webURL . Please let me know how I can make it work