# Accessing shared notebooks pages and sections for Onenote for business acoount

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote, onenote-api

I am integration onenote with my application. I am using below mentioned API to retrieve all notebooks that a user can potentially access to.

> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/notebooks?includesharednotebooks=true

I am able to retrieve all the notebooks owned by me and shared with me. The problem is in case on business account I am not able to further access the pages and sections which are inside shared notebooks. For all owned notebooks I can still access the pages and sections. How I can resolve this issue ?

This is a  blocker for me. Kindly revert

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issue with MS Graph Onenote get Notebooks API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46424446/issue-with-ms-graph-onenote-get-notebooks-api)

Comment: How are you trying to access the notebooks' sections after doing the API call "incliudeSharedNotebooks=true"?

Comment: Once I receive the shared notebook I call get section API with shared notebookId.                        Here the endpoint I am using is - me/onenote/notebook/{I'd}/sections.    I am not able to use /users endpoint since I don't have userId of the user who has shared notebook with me

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried accessing the notebooks by site?

1. Call the API
2. For any given notebook that doesn't belong to the owner, look for the site id given the site URL
3. Use that site id to do a ~sites/id/notes/... request

In Graph, you might be able to look up the site by keyword. Example:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=contoso
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me. Can I get any equivalent implementation using MS Graph API

Comment: I have already implemented few things using MS Graph and want to avoid rework. Please suggest me solution with MS Graph implementation

Comment: Added details on how you might be able to do this for graph

Comment: I tried that but that doesn't work. The weburl that I am getting is as - 
https://company-my.sharepoint.com/personal/pooja_dhannawat_company_com/Documents/Notebooks/Pooja_Work_1

When I try to search with hostname it doesn't work. That's giving me empty list

Comment: What if you search https://company-my.sharepoint.com/personal/pooja_dhannawat_company_com (without the notebook name? or even better, just the site name: pooja_dhannawat_company_com?

Comment: Tried all these combinations but it didn't work for me. Everytime this is giving me an empty list. When I tried using FromUrl api provided by Onenote to get site details it worked. The details of API are mentioned at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/onenote-get-content

Do we have any similar API provided by MS Graph. 

Please let me know any other details that I can share with you to get this resolved at priority.

Comment: any other way I could fetch the site Id. Kindly help