# Can't get sections in OneNote shared notebook

Tags: php, onenote-api

Using the OneNote API (via PHP and cURL) I can get the data for a **shared notebook** (not all data shown here):

```
"id": "1-ff693481-8376-40a5-936a-1d94aaf0acc5",
"self": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/1f1e0d22-2cab-43fa-944f-41ff04441b26/onenote/notebooks/1-ff693481-8376-40a5-936a-1d94aaf0acc5",
"displayName": "Config-003",
"sectionsUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/1f1e0d22-2cab-43fa-944f-41ff04441b26/onenote/notebooks/1-ff693481-8376-40a5-936a-1d94aaf0acc5/sections",
...
```

But when I use the `sectionsUrl` to get the **sections** within that notebook (or use the `id` to construct my own URL), all I get is a 404 error message:

`curl_exec() failed: The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found`

So what's a way of getting the **sections** (then the **pages** within them) that works?

Note: Answers to [Accessing shared notebooks pages and sections for Onenote for business acoount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46440803/accessing-shared-notebooks-pages-and-sections-for-onenote-for-business-acoount) don't answer my question.

[EDIT] Just to clarify in the light of Martin Zeitler's answer (now deleted): the access token is presented with the sections request, just as for the preceding notebooks request:

`CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("Content-Type: text/html", "Authorization: Bearer " . $encodedAccessToken)`

Answer (score 1):

Please use the GET-RecentNotebooks API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/notebook-getrecentnotebooks?view=graph-rest-1.0 to retrieve shared notebooks. And then for any shared notebook, use the POST-GetNotebookFromWebUrl API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/notebook-getnotebookfromweburl?view=graph-rest-1.0 to get the correct sections url

Comment: Thanks very much, Manjusha. I've got a bit of coding/recoding to do! I'll try it out and report back.

Comment: The sections URL that I get in that two-step GET/POST process gives me a 400 error. When I access the URL in Graph Explorer it also fails with Status Code 400 and gives me more detail: `"The OData query is invalid. The URI segment 'notebooks('1-8be13c7f-8846-4c74-955c-296eac376f9d')' is invalid after the segment 'notes'."` The full URL is: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/,676ba1b3-31c4-413b-b540-1561975a81f7,96002105-698a-4329-9524-4cd89c66a218/onenote/notebooks/1-8be13c7f-8846-4c74-955c-296eac376f9d/sections`

Comment: After more exploration, I discovered that the returned sections URL is missing a vital element: the URL for the SharePoint site itself (first segment after the `https://` in the  returned `oneNoteWebUrl`). This needs to be inserted before the first comma in the segment after `/sites/`. Once that is done, the full URL is correctly formed, no longer gives a 400 error, and returns a valid response from which sections data can be extracted.

Comment: This really does seem to be a defect in the `GetNotebookFromWebUrl` API request response, since the `pagesUrl` in the section resource does contain the segment that is missing in the `sectionsUrl` response to a `GetNotebookFromWebUrl` request.

Comment: +1 for Manjusha's answer because, even though it didn't give me the full story (see my previous comments), at least it did point me in the right direction.